# Finalize Sony Camcorder DVD

Tags: dvd, sony

Well, hello
I have had a Sony Video-Camera (SONY DCR-DVD105e) since 2006. It exports video to mini-dvd. Well I recently found the camera and its discs. However, I have lost its batteries and its adaptor, so I cannot turn it on. Unfortunately, many of the discs I had used are un-finalized and my computer does read them as blank dvd-s. As I cannot use the camera to finalize them, I used testdisk - photorec but the result was approximately 600 small .mpg videos and some .png photos (hahaha Obviously I didn't rec so many files! :p ). 
An idea is to use wine to install cdroller or something.. but generally I don't want to use windows software anymore, at least in my ubuntu!

Any ideas how to finalize the unfinalized dvds?

Answer (score 0):

I have used [ISObuster](https://secure.avangate.com/order/product.php?PRODS=160899&QTY=1&AFFILIATE=6732) in my windows days to accomplish that.  It will allow you to do data recovery of your video files that are on your DVD's.  You can try that under Wine, or look at [AcetoneISO](http://sourceforge.net/projects/acetoneiso/).

Comment: What to do with AcetoneISO?

Comment: You can try to see if it will allow you to save your videos, just like ISObuster.